grafana doesn't display .0 or .00 values ​even with unit locale format
I'm using grafana to display the data.  Let it come out as a decimal point value. Now the decimal value of .0 or .00 is converted to an integer instead of being displayed as .0 or .00, but decimal values ​​like .01 are still displayed normally.  Even though I set the unit to locale format, how should I fix it?
I'd like to know how to fix grafana's display of values ​​as .0 or .00.

You can specify number of decimals you need by setting Standard Options -> Decimals:

